# How to manage environment variables to store type boolean data in python

Tags: python, boolean, .env

I have looked at the responses in other related forums, but I could not find a clear answer.  I intended to comment on a related post to seek clarification, but my reputation was too low. So, I was forced to ask a new question.  Forgive me if this is incorrect protocol as I could not find the correct protocol for this situation.

Issue:
In an old post, I found this information:
Environment variables are always strings. A non-empty string is always boolean True, even if it contains the string "False".

You would need to compare the value with a string:

DEBUG = (os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG') == "True")
or, just remove the variable from your IIS settings altogether when you want to run in non-debug mode.

In my code, I have the following:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

DEBUG = bool(os.environ.get("DEBUG")) #environment variable "DEBUG" is set to False in my .env file
print(type(DEBUG)) #<class 'bool'>
```

I will use these statements in settings.py for my Django application to initialize the DEBUG variable. Is there anything wrong with writing the code this way as opposed to the initial method above?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If for some reason DEBUG is *not* in the env file. Then this code will throw an error. You should provide a default value. `bool(os.environ.get("DEBUG", 'False'))`

Comment: `bool('False')` is just as True as simply testing the string.  The `bool()` function doesn't look at the contents of the string.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim Why would this code raise an error? `os.environ` is an ordinary `Mapping`, so `.get` returns `None` if the environment variable doesn't exist. `'False'` also seems like a bad default, since that would make that expression `True` when the environment variable doesn't exist.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thank you!  I don't know why I often "pretend" in my mind that a function will do something it inherently doesn't!  This makes sense to me now.  The bool() function does not parse the string.  It only considers an empty or non-empty string.  The bool() fxn returns False for empty strings, '', and True for non-empty strings.

Therefore the initial method is correct because the expression DEBUG = os.environ.get("DEBUG") == "True" does check the contents of the string for an exact match and evaluates to True if the .env variable reads "True", but False otherwise.

Comment: I don't blame you for being confused, the other conversion functions `int()` and `float()` *do* look at their contents; `bool()` is the odd one out.  And just a hint, I'd use `DEBUG = os.environ.get("DEBUG").lower() == "true"` so you're not sensitive to letter case.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package `django-environ` that can help you manage those types of things.
It provides the ability to parse variables from the environment as well as from local `.env` files. And you can easily cast the values of those variables to certain types.

Example:

```
### Django settings base.py
import environ

# Initialize environ
env = environ.Env()

# Optionaly read .env file when working locally
root_env = str(ROOT_DIR.path('.env'))
if os.path.exists(root_env):
    env.read_env(root_env)

# Use env.bool() method to parse the env variable value and cast it to bool
DEBUG = env.bool('DJANGO_DEBUG', False)
```

Comment: Ok, and from my understanding, the following would also suffice if I were to continue with the dotenv package?:

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

DEBUG = os.environ.get("DJANGO_DEBUG", "False") == "True"

Comment: Yes, it would, but you would have to manually check each variable that you are using and cast it to a certain type, even apart from the `DJANGO_DEBUG` example.
In that case `DJANGO_DEBUG` could be set to 0 or 1, and your solution would break making it always `False` as well as just simply putting `true` instead of `True`. There are quite a couple of use cases you have to cover up.
As well as you could potential have a case where you have to parse a list from env variables and doing it manually would require additional "hacks" to make it work with just plain reading the values.